# Limit text to the width of sibling image / auto width in CSS

Tags: css, layout, html

I am essentially trying to create a version of the "figure" element (upcoming in HTML5), whereby I have an image with a short description below it.

However, I want to limit the width of this entire element to that of the image, so the text isn't wider than the image (wrapping to multiple lines if necessary).

Basic HTML:

```
<div class="figure">
<img src="..." alt="..." width="..." height="..." /><br />
A description for the image
</div>
```

I'm well-versed with CSS but I can't think of any pure CSS solution, without adding a `style="width:100px"` to the `div` to match the image width.

**Update**: After a bit of searching and thinking, the best method seems to be using an inline width on the div. I will keep the width attribute on the image, in case I wish the div to be a bit wider than the image (for example to accomodate a longer caption).

This approach also means I could have two images side-by-side with a caption below. If I have a set of images the same size, I can of course add an extra style to each `div`.

Thanks to everyone who answered!

Comment: What's wrong with setting the width on the div?

Comment: I just don't think it's good code. For starters it means I'm duplicating the width declaration. If I change the image width I must change the div width too. (I know they're only next to each other.) There is a solution below though.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Stylesheet**

```
div.figure img,
div.figure div.caption {
    width: 100%;
}
div.figure div {
    overflow: hidden;
    white-space: nowrap;
}
```

*note: to enable wrapping just remove that last css line*

**HTML**

```
<div class="figure" style="width:150px;">
    <img src="logo.png" alt="logo" />
    <div class="caption">A description for the image</div>
</div>
```

I've checked it in Chrome, Firefox and IE7 and it looks good in all three. I realise this has the width on the div and not the img, but at least you only need to set the width in one place. Short of using css-expressions (IE only) I can't see a way of setting the outer divs width to the width of the first child element.

Comment: I normally put a width/height on images because it's better for browser rendering - no layout jumping as the page loads, and the layout is preserved when images are unavailable. In this case I guess I'd put a height on the image and it would inherit the width.

Comment: Also the * selector is a bad idea. I could have more elements in the caption (eg links) that might get messed up. It should be replaced with simply `img` (`duv` is 100% by default)

Comment: fair comment on the * selector

Answer (score 23):

This could also be accomplished using `'display: table-caption'` for the caption, as follows:

#### HTML

```
<div class="wrapper">
  <img src="image.jpg" />
  <div class="caption">My caption...</div>
</div>
```

#### Stylesheet

```
.wrapper {
  display: table;
}

.caption {
  display: table-caption;
  caption-side: bottom;
}
```

This block can also be floated left of right of other text. I've tested this in IE8+. Here's a JSBin example: http://jsbin.com/xiyevovelixu/1

Comment: This solution will only work as long as you don't need any borders or background at `.wrapper`, since both will collapse to the image only. This is consistent in Chrome, FF & Edge

Answer (score 9):

For setting the width to match the image automatically you could use

```
.figure {
  display: table;
  width: 1px;
}
```

This makes the div behave like a table (not supported in Internet Explorer). Or you could use a table instead of the div. I don't think there is another way of setting the width automatically.

**Edit**: The simplest way is to forget about the auto width and set it by hand. If it is really needed you can use JavaScript or a table. In this case the use of a table is not so ugly because you are addressing a limitation of the HTML version. In the case of server-side scripting you could also set the width when generating the page.

Comment: Your example by setting the display doesn't work in IE7.  Not sure about IE6.

Comment: According to http://www.quirksmode.org/css/display.html it's not supported by released versions of IE. I guess the only option then is to use a table.

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem and after reading [this](http://www.cs.tut.fi/~jkorpela/www/captions.html) decided to use an inline-style on the surrounding element. Seems the better solution over using a table to me.

Answer (score 2):

You can also acheive this using the following [solution proposed by Temani Afif in his blog post](https://dev.to/afif/responsive-text-based-on-image-size-36n9) (All credits to him, I just don't want the solution to be forgotten)

```html
<div class="box">
   <img>
   <h1>Lorem ipsum dolor ..</h1>
</div>
```

```css
.box {
  display: inline-block;
}
h1 {
  width: 0;
  min-width: 100%;
}
```

Make the container inline-block, and makes the h1 (or whatever text tag you use) occupy the space dictated by the sibling element. It's essentially a hack, but it works! No unintended semantic consequences like the [table solutions](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25386583/18620006)

Answer (score 0):

You could use the `display:table` solution for all other browsers, and a [CSS Behaviour](http://www.google.nl/search?hl=en&rlz=1C1GGLS_en-USNL292NL304&q="internet+explorer"+css+behaviour&btnG=Search) for Internet Explorer.